# Transposing Punch Times with same Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please I would like to be able to transpose ClockIns and ClockOuts with same Dates and EmpIDs into the same row expanding column headers as needed since the data set has about 800,000 rows. The problem is that I have some 12Am (00:00:00) clock Ins and the table doesn't have them in order.

For Example:

| EID | ASSOCIATE_NAME | TIME_PUNCH_DATE | TIME_IN | TIME_OUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-10-30 | 20:30:00 PM | 00:29:00 AM |
| 1 | John | 2022-10-30 | 11:08:00 AM | 15:40:00 PM |
| 1 | John | 2022-10-30 | 16:10:00 PM | 20:00:00 PM |

What I need:

| EID | ASSOCIATE_NAME | TIME_PUNCH_DATE | In_Punch1 | Out_Punch1 | In_Punch2 | Out_Punch2 | In_Punch3 | Out_Punch3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-10-30 | 11:08:00 AM | 15:40:00 PM | 16:10:00PM | 20:00:00PM | 20:30:00PM | 00:29:00AM |

I tried this query which worked perfectly fine except in the rows in question (the ones with 00:00:00 times):

```
  (SELECT TIME_IN
   FROM
     (SELECT TIME_IN,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID,
                                             [TIME_PUNCH_DATE]
                                ORDER BY EID,
                                         [TIME_PUNCH_DATE],
                                         TIME_IN) RN
      FROM [dbo].[PandaExpress_shortv2] C2
      WHERE C1.EID = C2.EID
        AND C1.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] = C2.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] ) F
   WHERE RN = 1) 'In_Punch1',
  (SELECT TIME_OUT
   FROM
     (SELECT TIME_OUT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID,
                                             [TIME_PUNCH_DATE]
                                ORDER BY EID,
                                         [TIME_PUNCH_DATE],
                                         TIME_OUT) RN
      FROM [dbo].[PandaExpress_shortv2] C2
      WHERE C1.EID = C2.EID
        AND C1.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] = C2.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] ) F
   WHERE RN = 1) 'Out_Punch1',
  (SELECT TIME_IN
   FROM
     (SELECT TIME_IN,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID,
                                             [TIME_PUNCH_DATE]
                                ORDER BY EID,
                                         [TIME_PUNCH_DATE],
                                         TIME_IN) RN
      FROM [dbo].[PandaExpress_shortv2] C2
      WHERE C1.EID = C2.EID
        AND C1.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] = C2.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] ) F
   WHERE RN = 2) 'In_Punch2',
  (SELECT TIME_OUT
   FROM
     (SELECT TIME_OUT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID,
                                             [TIME_PUNCH_DATE]
                                ORDER BY EID,
                                         [TIME_PUNCH_DATE],
                                         TIME_OUT) RN
      FROM [dbo].[PandaExpress_shortv2] C2
      WHERE C1.EID = C2.EID
        AND C1.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] = C2.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] ) F
   WHERE RN = 2) 'Out_Punch2',
  (SELECT TIME_IN
   FROM
     (SELECT TIME_IN,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID,
                                             [TIME_PUNCH_DATE]
                                ORDER BY EID,
                                         [TIME_PUNCH_DATE],
                                         TIME_IN) RN
      FROM [dbo].[PandaExpress_shortv2] C2
      WHERE C1.EID = C2.EID
        AND C1.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] = C2.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] ) F
   WHERE RN = 3) 'In_Punch3',
  (SELECT TIME_OUT
   FROM
     (SELECT TIME_OUT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID,
                                             [TIME_PUNCH_DATE]
                                ORDER BY EID,
                                         [TIME_PUNCH_DATE],
                                         TIME_OUT) RN
      FROM [dbo].[PandaExpress_shortv2] C2
      WHERE C1.EID = C2.EID
        AND C1.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] = C2.[TIME_PUNCH_DATE] ) F
   WHERE RN = 3) 'Out_Punch3'
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @DaleK I edited the question pasting the query I tried

Comment: What if one person punches in and out 17 times? Or if they punch in twice and forget to punch out in between (e.g. punch out is null)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know the most is three punch-ins/punch-outs per day:

```
SELECT EID, ASSOCIATE_NAME, TIME_PUNCH_DATE, 
  In_Punch1  = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN TIME_IN END),
  Out_Punch1 = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN TIME_OUT END),
  In_Punch2  = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN TIME_IN END),
  Out_Punch2 = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN TIME_OUT END),
  In_Punch3  = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN TIME_IN END),
  Out_Punch3 = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN TIME_OUT END)
FROM 
(
  SELECT EID, ASSOCIATE_NAME, TIME_PUNCH_DATE, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY EID, TIME_PUNCH_DATE ORDER BY TIME_IN)
  FROM dbo.PandaExpress_shortv2
) AS Agg
GROUP BY EID, ASSOCIATE_NAME, TIME_PUNCH_DATE;
```

However, it's unlikely you can be certain there will never be more than three, so you'll need this to be dynamic.

```
DECLARE @maxRN int;

SELECT @maxRN = MAX(c) FROM 
(
  SELECT c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EID, TIME_PUNCH_DATE)
  FROM dbo.PandaExpress_shortv2
) AS BiggestCount;

DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max), 
        @agg  nvarchar(max);

;WITH ASet AS
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',', @maxRN-1),',')
)
SELECT @agg = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(' 
  In_Punch' ,rn,'  = MAX(CASE rn WHEN ',rn,' THEN TIME_IN END),
  Out_Punch',rn, ' = MAX(CASE rn WHEN ',rn,' THEN TIME_OUT END)'
), ',') FROM ASet;

SET @sql = CONCAT(N'SELECT EID, ASSOCIATE_NAME, TIME_PUNCH_DATE, ', 
  @agg, N'    FROM 
    (
      SELECT EID, ASSOCIATE_NAME, TIME_PUNCH_DATE, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
             (PARTITION BY EID, TIME_PUNCH_DATE ORDER BY TIME_IN)
      FROM dbo.PandaExpress_shortv2
    ) AS Agg
    GROUP BY EID, ASSOCIATE_NAME, TIME_PUNCH_DATE;');

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

[Working example in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RwR_oGjc).

Comment: Aaron, thank you so much!!! So far the dynamic solution looks like did the job. Thanks again